# What is the difference between "after" and "afterwards"?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Sometimes I hear someone speaking "after" and sometimes "afterwards", what is the difference between these words?

Comment: *afterwards* is an adverb while *after* can be an adjective, preposition, conjunction or adverb.

Comment: *afterwards* is usually used as an adverb to imply "after an event that already has happened/mentioned". However, after can be adjective, adverbial conjunction, adverb, or preposition.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/after-afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a native speaker. Feel free to correct my mistakes.

According to [article in English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/after-afterwards):

1. Only `after` can be used as preposition:

   > I will meet her after dinner.
   >   <s>I will meet her afterwards dinner.</s>
2. Only `after` can be used as conjunction:

   > I will meet her after she finishes her work.
   >   <s>I will meet her afterwards she finishes her work.</s>
3. Both `after` and `afterwards` can be used as adverb:

   - Both `after` and `afterwards` can be precised by exact (`3 years after/afterwards`, `2 days after/afterwards`) or inexact (`soon after/afterwards`, `shortly after/afterwards`, `ever after/afterwards`) time period specification:

     > I payed all my debts and left the city three days after.
     >   I payed all my debts. Three days afterwards I left the city.
   - I'm not sure if `after` can be used as adverb when having no dependent words. `Afterwards` is widely used in this case:

     > ??? *I cut the chicken and I washed my hands after.* ???
     >   I cut the chicken and afterwards I washed my hands.

   `After` (when used as adverb) has to be put in the end. While, according to [topic in WordReference Forum](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/afterwards-position.2400942/), `afterwards` is usually put before clause/phrase it relates to, it can also be put in the end to make special emphasis:

   > I cut the chicken and washed my hands three minutes after.
   >   I cut the chicken and three minutes afterwards I washed my hands.
   >   
   >   — Did you wash your hands before touching the chicken?
   >   — No, I cut the chicken and washed my hands afterwards.